# como trabalhar com SASS/LESS em tempo real?

Tags: css, sass, less

Recentemente dei atenção para pré-processadores de `css` como `less` e `sass` pois vi vantagens em utilizá-los, porém vejo a necessidade de um workflow para que o `css` gerado seja compilado automaticamente. A princípio, como é possível obter os resultados do código em tempo real ou automatizar o build do mesmo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende um pouco dos pacotes que estiveres a usar mas eu uso o [`watcher-lessc`](https://github.com/liuhong1happy/watcher-lessc) que escuta mudanças nos ficheiros e recompila em milisegundos.

```
npm install watcher-lessc
watcher-lessc -i ./css/style.less -o ./css/style.css
```

Answer (score -1):

Podes ver um tutorial neste link:

[Compiling less file gulp](https://webkul.com/blog/compiling-less-file-gulp/)

Se quiser em tempo real utilize a dica do Sergio utilizando um watcher.

Mas para ser em "tempo real", tudo dependerá da sua build e do seu processo de desenvolvimento.

Abraços!

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/131277)

Comment: Ok, depois eu reviso a resposta. Mas aqui no stack as respostas tem que ser muito mamãozinho com açúcar...